# Preparing Pyramid chart in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I need to develop a pyramid chart with Angularjs. Here I am using angularcharts.min.js & charts.min.js libraries. In production server the requirejs will also be included.

Need some suggestions for preceding in a better way.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should note that there are 2 major types of chart and graph: the static chart and the dynamic chart.

the choice between the two depends on the context of use,for static graph the data are too static and does not need updating, but for the dynamic graph data must be updated there ara tow aproach to update the data:

-1 with ajax by using timing

-2 with socketio push from server)